# Who are the 5 terrestrial Rishies that were mentioned in Rig Veda II.34.14?

Tags: rama, rig-veda, rishi, maruts

[Rig Veda II.34.14](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02034.htm), dedicated to Maruts, narrates briefly about 5 terrestrial rishies

> तानियानो महि वरूथमूतय उप घेदेना नमसा गर्णीमसि | तरितो न यान पञ्च
>   होतॄनभिष्टय आववर्तदवराञ्चक्रियावसे ||
>
> tāniyāno mahi varūthamūtaya upa ghedenā namasā ghṛṇīmasi | trito na
>   yān pañca hotṝnabhiṣṭaya āvavartadavarāñcakriyāvase ||

Translation of [H.H. Wilson (P.179)](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Rigveda_Samhita_English_Vol_II/#book/207) is as follows:

> Imploring them for ample wealth. and (having recourse to him) for
>   protection. we glorify them with this praise: like the ***five Chief
>   Priests*** whom **TRITA detained** for the (performance of) the sacrifice.
>   and to ***protect it with their weapons***.

---

This mantra is referring to

- 5 Chief Priests, who TRITA detained
- for protection of his sacrifice with their weapons
- TRITA was used in other mantras to indicate a MAHARSHI

---

My questions are:

1. Who were the 5 Chief Priests, who protected the sacrifice of TRITA?
2. Was this protection of a sacrifice allegorical and/or a forerunner to protection of Yagna, performed by Sage Viswamitra by Sri Rama and Lakshmana, with their weapons?

Answer (score 2):

They are Five Prāṇa​s i.e Prāṇa, Apāna, Vyāna, Udāna, Samāna​ who constitutes Prāṇamaya​ Kosha (see Taittiriya Upanishad 2.3.1) and hence the body. They are considered equivalent to five Hotṛs in doing Yajna. Take a look at such type of Yajna mentioned in Bhagavad Gita 4.29.

- [Here](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart2/page/n200) is the [Sayanacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayana)'s Sanskrit commentary on this verse:

  > [image]

I do not have any reference to translation of this commentary but I've highlighted the Sanskrit text which talks about five Prāṇas as five Hotṛs.

- I have confirmed this interpretation from **Rigveda Bhāṣā Bhāṣya** by Pandit Jaydeva Sharma; you can read it on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/RigvedaSamhitaPartIIAryaSahityaMandirAjmer1931/page/n718):

  > [image]

  Note: Rigveda Bhāṣā Bhāṣya is one of the reliable commentary on Rigveda by Indian author mentioned [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36997/277)

So, **five Hotṛs (priests), here refers to five Prāṇa​s i.e 1. Prāṇa, 2. Apāna, 3. Vyāna, 4. Udāna, 5. Samāna.**

Comment: @Pandya: I had guessed these 5 pranas.  However, it was stated in the Mantra that they protected the sacrifice with weapons.  Can you explain this aspect?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, the **five Chief Priests** whom TRITA detained (Rig Veda II.34.14) are 5 Indriyas (sense organs) - i.e. **eyes, ear, nose, tongue, and skin**.

If we re-visit the crux of the mantra in question, we can understand that the 5 sense organs will goad humans to remain materialistic.

> "  .....like the **five Chief Priests** whom **TRITA** detained for
> the (performance of) the sacrifice. and to protect it with their
> weapons."

- TRITA indicates **a sage**
- sacrifice indicate the **spiritual practice/asceticism**

The sage was saying that one should detain the 5 sense organs, who are very powerful with their weapons, for doing spiritual practice/asceticism

---

Even many ascetics acknowledged that the 5 sense organs are very powerful to overcome with.

Rig Veda [III.37.9](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv03037.htm) says

> indriyāṇi śatakrato yā te janeṣu pañcasu | indra tāni taā vṛṇe ||
>
> Indra, the object of many rites, I regard the organs of sense that
> **exist in the 5 races** (of beings dependent) on thee, as thine

Indra, who was alluded as Brahman in Rig Veda, will protect the sage, from the very powerful weapons of 5 sense organs, which are under the control of Indra.

---

Comment: I see tri ta bhur bhovas swagha (vyahruthi) with pranava is tri ta if you do pranayama with vyahruthi this five sense are controlled..