# Verses for detachment from Arishadvarga or Shadripu?

Tags: indra, kama

Verses for detachment from Arishadvarga or Shadripu:

1. Lust (Kama)
2. Anger (Krodha)
3. Greed (Lobha)
4. Arrogance (Mada)
5. Attachment (Moha)
6. Jealousy (Matsarya)

स्त्रीष्वध्यासितचित्तस्य ये पुंसः शुक्रबिन्दवः।

ते सुखाय न मन्यन्ते स्वेदजा इव ते तथा॥५५॥

The drops of semen of a person who is lustful with his mind engaged in women when dropped, they cannot make him comfortable like the drops of sweat.

This Verse prevents My lustful thoughts.. I want verses which detach Me from Arishadvarga or Shadripu..

Indra deva is said to test person with Arishadvarga or Shadripu.

Any Mantra on Indra Deva related to Arishadvarga or Shadripu..

Comment: It is a duplicate of this question (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16527/3869).  Indra was eulogised in Rig Veda.  As far as I know, there was no mention about Arishadvarga or Shadripu in Rig Veda.  However, there was a mention about 5 senses, which are the cause for man's materialistic tendencies.(https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37565/3869).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shadripu in Hindu texts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16527/shadripu-in-hindu-texts)

Comment: I looking for verses, (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16527/shadripu-in-hindu-texts) << This doesnt have any verse related to Arishadvarga or Shadripu

Comment: Indra was eulogised in Rig Veda. As far as I know, there was no mention about Arishadvarga or Shadripu in Rig Veda. However, there was a mention about 5 senses, which are the cause for man's materialistic tendencies.(hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37565/3869).