# Mantra for Indriyas and Arishadvarga/Shadripu?

Tags: mantras, indriyas

Mantras to win over Indriyas and detach from Shadripu/Arishadvargas.

Protect ones from Minds Internal Enemies.

Comment: I heard chanting rAma would help.. wondering if there are any other.

Comment: A duplicate question but with no answer.-https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37569/verses-for-detachment-from-arishadvarga-or-shadripu